# I can`t send my object with socket.io function socket.emit() to node server. How can I take this data with functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

I have a Dot object, and I want to sent to node server with socket.emit('add_dot_init', new Dot())
But when I send this Data, My server getting this object like this
`{ x: 15, y: 75, alp: 3.487639104390228 }`

What I want to do? This dot object will be a client object. and clients will control this dots..
so I take back from server this data and run move() function in this class
like:

```
dots.push(new Dot())
dots[0].move();
```

But I cant take back this object from server cuz its coming like

```
{ x: 15, y: 75, alp: 3.487639104390228 }
```

---

How can I take this data with functions?

```
class Dot{
constructor(){
    this.x = 15;
    this.y = 75;
    this.alp = random(51)
}

move(){
    dot.x +=5;
}

show(){
    fill(0);
    ellipse(this.x,this.y,30,30);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The communication is done over websocket, so behind the scenes you are just sending a JSON string to the server and back to the client. This means that whenever you transport the Dot instance over websocket, it gets serialized and deserialized into regular javascript object without any cutom methods. If you want to use The Dot on the server or client you would have to use a constructor that will initialize it based on the plain object it receives from the websocket:

```
class Dot{
    constructor(dot){
        if (dot) {
            this.x = dot.x;
            this.y = dot.y;
            this.alp = dot.alp;
        } else {
            this.x = 15;
            this.y = 75;
            this.alp = random(51)
        }
    }

    move(){
        dot.x +=5;
    }

    show(){
        fill(0);
        ellipse(this.x,this.y,30,30);
    }
}
```

Once you receive the message on server/client just call something like `const dot = new Dot(response);` Where `response` is the value you've received via websocket, then you are able to use `dot.move` method